# TestNg: getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 while executing test with maven

Tags: java, maven, testng

I ran into this weird issue recently (3-4 weeks) where I am getting "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0" for one of the tests in the test suite.
The test method runs fine till a certain point before failing with the below exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeWithTimeoutWithNewExecutor(MethodInvocationHelper.java:289)
org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeWithTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:246)
org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:667)
org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1297)
org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:283)
org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:120)
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:386)
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:323)
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:143)
```

Any help or pointer is highly appreciated.
The issue is happening only when I do a "mvn test". It runs fine when I run it from the IDEA itself.

Thanks

Comment: You should be more specific about the test that is failing and what changed into your project before test failing. If it's an integration test, could be due to a polluted environment. The integration tests order could be different on IDEA and Maven, thus the fact that the error is only present on Maven. Try also to log what is happening into the test so you can debug after, it will help you figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Please check if the test in question has something to do with timeouts. Recently there was an issue filed in TestNG related to timeouts (details can be found in [GITHUB-1493](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1493) ) which I fixed.

Your stacktrace that you shared, is pointing me to this issue only.

If its related to that, then am afraid there's no workaround but to start either start using the snapshot version and start using TestNG v.6.13 or higher (when it gets released) or exclude that particular test in question for now (again till TestNG 6.13 which contains the fix is released).

Comment: Thanks Krishnan!
I will try again and will update you with my findings

Appreciate your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

I was googling this issue myself (I was running TestNG v6.11) and when I read Krishnan Mahadevan's comment above, I tried moving to 6.10.  Caused me no issues, and now the `@Test` `timeOut` throws a `ThreadTimeoutException` instead of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  Just in case you want to give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

I was using testng release 6.11 and had the same issue with configuring a timeout.

```
@Test(timeOut=1000)
```

Upgrading to 6.13.1 and problem went away and I am getting the expected `ThreadTimeoutException`.